# How to get rid of Error "Missing Expression" while using the UPDATE CASE

Tags: sql, oracle, case

I want to mass update the `Paytotaxid` .. I am using the `Case` Statement.. as shown below

```
UPDATE Persons 
   SET Paytotaxid = CASE Paytotaxid 
                      WHEN = ''
                      THEN ''
                      ELSE 'XXXX' || RIGHT(TaxID,4)
                    END;
```

But I keep getting the error *Missing Expression*.

**Current State**

```
PERSONID LASTNAME FIRSTNAME ADDRESS  CITY PAYTOTAXID TAXID

11 Tom B. Erichsen Skagen 21 Stavanger Norway 123-57-2988 123-57-2988 

22 Joe B. Erichsen Skagen 21 Stavanger minneapolis 123-57-3338 123-57-3338 

33 Mary B. Erichsen Skagen 21 Stavanger Norway 123-57-4444 123-57-4444 

44 Jaya B. Erichsen Skagen 21 Stavanger Norway
```

**Expected  Result**

```
PERSONID LASTNAME FIRSTNAME ADDRESS CITY PAYTOTAXID TAXID

11 Tom B. Erichsen Skagen 21 Stavanger Norway XXXXX2988 123-57-2988 

22 Joe B. Erichsen Skagen 21 Stavanger minneapolis XXXXX3338 123-57-3338 

33 Mary B. Erichsen Skagen 21 Stavanger Norway XXXXX4444 123-57-4444 

44 Jaya B. Erichsen Skagen 21 Stavanger Norway
```

Comment: Take out the '=' after WHEN

Comment: I get an error saying -- ORA-00904: "RIGHT": invalid identifier.. Is "Right" not valid in oracle ?

Comment: No, Right is not a valid function in Oracle (11gR2).  You will have to use `SUBSTR(TaxId, LENGTH(TaxID)-4)`

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the `=` sign in the wrong place, you were trying to do an equality check with an empty string, which won't work in Oracle, because, empty strings are interpreted as `NULL`, and nulls need to be checked using `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL`.

But in this case, you seem to only want to update the field if it's not null.  In that case, you don't need a `case` at all.  You just need to filter out the rows you don't want to update using a normal `where` clause.

```
update persons
   set Paytotaxid = 'XXXX' || SUBSTR(TaxID,-4)
 where Paytotaxid is not null
```

**EDIT**: As per the comments, replaced the `RIGHT` function, which is invalid in Oracle.

Comment: I get an error saying -- ORA-00904: "RIGHT": invalid identifier.. Is "Right" not valid in oracle ?

Comment: I asume he copied the RIGHT() from your example, assuming it was a  function of yours. If you want the rightmost four characters of a string use SUBSTR(TaxId,-4)

Comment: @Michael: Thanks.  I didn't spot that.  That's the problem when the SQL has many little problems.

Comment: Thanks Everyone.. the error is gone .. but the value in paytotaxid is blank and sql query updates the blank columns to XXXXX

Comment: the -4 is causing SUBSTR to return NULL, see my comment above with my answer.

Comment: @DBug: Why would `SUBSTR(TaxID,-4)` return null? It would only return null if `TaxID` is shorter than 4 chars or is null.  But that is normal.

Comment: @user5704279: You say the value of `paytotaxid` is blank.  But what does that mean exactly?  A single space?  What?  At some point, you also need to put in a little effort.

Comment: Thanks Everyone for all your help ... Amazing guys ..!!

Comment: Thanks sstan.. I'll take it up from here

Comment: @sstan, according to Oracle doc for SUBSTR: "If substring_length is less than 1, then Oracle returns null." (I'm using 11gR2)

Comment: If you want the last four (or less) characters, try SUBSTR(TaxID,-1*(LEAST(LENGTH(taxID),4)))